# Getting pics to line up right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get 3 things to set on the same line. One of them is a pic the other 2 are going to be text fields. this is what i have so far. I have an img in all three spots just to have a place holder.

```
<div class="top"><img src="Images/cmdg.jpg" ></img></div>
<div class="top1"><img src="Images/cmdg.jpg" ></img></div>
<div class="top2"><img src="Images/cmdg.jpg" ></img></div>

<style>
img{
width: 580px;
height:auto;
margin-left:580px;
margin-right: 574px;
margin-top: -18px;
border-color:white;
border-style:solid;
border-radius:50%;
border-width: 2px;
}

.top {
    float:left;
    margin: 33%;
    width:180;
    height:auto;
}
.top1 {
    float:none;
    margin: 33%;
    width:180;
    height:auto;
}
.top2 {
    float:right;
    margin: 33%;
    width:180;
    height:auto;
}
```

At this point it will stack them on top of each other, or just not look right. 
Please help

Comment: Why do you have your divs numbered? Also, img tags are self closing.

Comment: I added the <style>, thank you for that. And I am not sure why I numbered them really. Think it was to keep track of them and just forgot to remove the numbers.

Comment: Really after inspecting the elements it is the size of the elements that is doing it and I can not get them to change to 33% each.

Comment: you have not defined `border-width: xxpx;` and the tag correct => `<div class="top"><img src="Images/cmdg.jpg" ></div>`

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected the div tags. and added the border-width to the code. But it did not put them all inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give margins according to the width of the window. When I remove/reduce the margins it works perfectly.
**Try the code below and understand it.**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
img{
    width: 400px;
    height:auto;
    //reduce the margins below as the screen size is 1300 something hence decide accordingly.
    /*margin-left:580px;
    margin-right: 574px;*/
    margin-top: -18px;
    border-color:white;
    border-style:solid;
    border-radius:50%;
}

.top {
    float:left;
    height:auto;
}
.top1 {
    float:left;
    height:auto;
}
.top2 {
    float:left;
    height:auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="top"><img src="Images/cmdg.jpg"  ></div>
<div class="top1"><img src="Images/cmdg.jpg"  ></div>
<div class="top2"><img src="Images/cmdg.jpg"  ></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked very will, but the last img "top2" is set to the right and below the other two imgs. Any reason why it would do that?

Comment: never mind I was missing the float:left; on all of them. It works great thank you

Comment: There's a basic rule. If your window is 640 X 480 then width being 640, for all images to lie in a line, the width properth of image class should be less than 640/3. Try this with your screen size!

Comment: how would I make it so they auto adjust to fit any screen? I know that it is % and not px, but not sure how.

Comment: Read about responsive web design.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
img{
width: 380px;
height:auto;
border-width:6px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:white;
border-radius:50%;
}
.content{
    display:table;
    margin:auto;
}
.div{
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    padding:5px;
}
</style>
<div class="content">
<div class="div top"><img src="Images/cmdg.jpg" ></div>
<div class="div top1"><img src="Images/cmdg.jpg" ></div>
<div class="div top2"><img src="Images/cmdg.jpg" ></div>
</div>
```